# What is label_keys parameter good for in a Classifier - Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

What is `label_keys` parameter good for in a Classifier.
Can you visualize the labeled data on Tensorboard at the Embeddings section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in tensorboard, but the predict method can return the class names instead of numbers if you provide label_keys.